# An adjective meaning having a more specific domain or subject?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives

> The first view is about knowledge generally. But the second view is
>   only about scientific knowledge. The second view is _____ .

What word (adjective) or adjectival phrase to put in the blank?

"Specific" doesn't sound specific enough. (Pun intended)

And I don't know if "Domain-specific" can be used in the above sentence.

Comment: The usual way to say this is "more narrowly scoped", if an adjectival phrase will do. 'More precisely targeted/directed' are also idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is worth being offered as an answer.

Comment: Then you should add the tag 'phrases'; I'll add the answer.

Comment: Would the down-voter please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly common way to say this is **more narrowly scoped** (an adjectival phrase).

> **scope** 1 noun ...
>
> 3. The extent of a given activity or subject that is involved, treated, or relevant: *the scope of the debate* ... Synonyms ... range
>      [[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scoped)]

(the senses of the verb and participial adjective follow).

> **narrow**: adjective ...
>
> 2. Limited in area or scope [[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/narrow)]

(again, the sense of the adjective-modifier [traditionally 'adverb'] follows).

The phrase has become a reasonably strong collocation; examples from the internet are:

> Narrowly scoped subset-analyses were performed additionally for
>   living-donor transplants, pediatric transplants, as well as cases with
>   prolonged cold ischemic time (CIT).
>
> [[Comparable outcome of liver
>   transplantation ...; Alexander Kaltenborn et
>   al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4193146/)]

......................

> Outsourcing contracts are trending toward smaller deals. Outsourcing
>   firms should also consider establishing more narrowly scoped
>   relationships [[Supply Chain Focused Manufacturing Planning and
>   Control By W. C.
>   Benton](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NhvTCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=%22more+narrowly+scoped%22&source=bl&ots=exRdNQbeyN&sig=ACfU3U1Jt_vGIfTKB4DJp42jR50PDV7JBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi74NOpweLkAhWTuHEKHRVjBkA4FBDoATAAegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%22more%20narrowly%20scoped%22&f=false)]

...............

**More precisely targeted** and **more precisely directed** are also idiomatic.